# Talend - MySQL broken pipe error

Tags: mysql, jdbc, talend

We started having a broken pipe issue this past Saturday with a job that gets run via a quartz scheduler during the early morning of each day.  Below are some details on this.

The job consists of a native java class that calls Talend based jobs.  Each of these Talend based jobs are getting the broken pipe error.  Curious enough, when I run the same java class that gets submitted via the scheduler, no errors get thrown and the jobs run successfully.  Also, this job stream runs in Tomcat.

Is there something I should do within the Talend jobs to see if a connection is available first?  As you will see in the following jdbc parameters used for the tMysqlConnection component, the autoreconnect option is set to on.

jdbc parameters are as follows  are "noDatetimeStringSync=true&connectTimeout=0&socketTimeout=0&autoReconnect=true"

Below is the stacktrace from this morning's job failure.

Any input is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
    Exception in component tMysqlConnection_1  
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received     from the server was 344,265,715 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 344,265,792 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor840.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5282)
    at umaxbalancing_etl.csxdemand_masterservice_0_1.CSXDemand_MasterService.tMysqlConnection_1Process(CSXDemand_MasterService.java:2381)
    at umaxbalancing_etl.csxdemand_masterservice_0_1.CSXDemand_MasterService.tFileList_2Process(CSXDemand_MasterService.java:2284)
    at umaxbalancing_etl.csxdemand_masterservice_0_1.CSXDemand_MasterService.tFileExist_1Process(CSXDemand_MasterService.java:1146)
    at umaxbalancing_etl.csxdemand_masterservice_0_1.CSXDemand_MasterService.tJava_2Process(CSXDemand_MasterService.java:1054)
    at umaxbalancing_etl.csxdemand_masterservice_0_1.CSXDemand_MasterService.tJava_1Process(CSXDemand_MasterService.java:972)
    at umaxbalancing_etl.csxdemand_masterservice_0_1.CSXDemand_MasterService.runJobInTOS(CSXDemand_MasterService.java:4370)
    at umaxbalancing_etl.csxdemand_masterservice_0_1.CSXDemand_MasterService.runJob(CSXDemand_MasterService.java:4079)
    at com.rez1.dws.mid.etl.engine.extract.talend.RunTalendDailyJobs.runCSXDemandExtract(RunTalendDailyJobs.java:45)
    at com.rez1.dws.mid.etl.engine.extract.talend.RunTalendDailyJobs.dailyJobs(RunTalendDailyJobs.java:28)
    at com.rez1.dws.mid.etl.engine.master.service.DWMasterETLServiceImpl.processTalendDailyJobs(DWMasterETLServiceImpl.java:401)
    at com.rez1.dws.mid.etl.engine.master.service.DWMasterETLServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$13fc5e62.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:91)
    at com.rez1.common.processmonitor.ProcessMonitor.handleNestedInvocation(ProcessMonitor.java:440)
    at com.rez1.common.processmonitor.ProcessMonitor.handleJoinPoint(ProcessMonitor.java:404)
    at com.rez1.op.core.performance.aspect.OperationalProgressMonitorAspect.operationalMonitor(OperationalProgressMonitorAspect.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:91)
    at com.rez1.dws.mid.etl.engine.aspect.DWMasterETLExceptionMonitorAspect.monitorForExceptions(DWMasterETLExceptionMonitorAspect.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.rez1.dws.mid.etl.engine.master.service.DWMasterETLServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ca0f48f4.processTalendDailyJobs(<generated>)
    at com.rez1.apipublish.dws.facade.DataWarehouseFacadeImpl.talendDailyJob(DataWarehouseFacadeImpl.java:169)
    at com.rez1.apipublish.dws.facade.DataWarehouseFacadeImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$fcc756cf.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:91)
    at com.rez1.common.processmonitor.ProcessMonitor.handleFirstInvocation(ProcessMonitor.java:369)
    at com.rez1.common.processmonitor.ProcessMonitor.handleJoinPoint(ProcessMonitor.java:402)
    at com.rez1.op.core.performance.aspect.OperationalProgressMonitorAspect.operationalMonitor(OperationalProgressMonitorAspect.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.rez1.apipublish.dws.facade.DataWarehouseFacadeImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$521e5519.talendDailyJob(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy75.talendDailyJob(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:205)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:38)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3852)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of the broken pipe error I encountered.

The broken pipe error was being thrown due to my not closing down certain database connections
from within the Talend jobs. These connections at issue were connections that were defined in native
java (via the tJava component). It was incorrectly assumed by me that by referencing a previously
defined connection (for connection attributes), the connection resources would be closed and
released.

With the above in mind, I was actually creating a new connection as listed below and had to
specifically commit the connection and then close it out.  The item to take note of here is the use
of the commit on the connection.  The broken pipe error was still being thrown with just the close
of the connection.  It was not until the commit was added did the broken pipe errors cease and that
was due to the connection being closed properly.

Hindsight being what it is... when using the Talend components (and not native java code) for
the connection definition and closing of that connection, the autoCommit feature is available to the
tMysqlCOnnection as well as the commit option being available for the close connection option being
available on the tMysqlCommit component.  These two options allow for the prevention of a broken
pipe error and is why I only encountered broken pipe errors with the connections used by the tJava
components.  Makes sense now.

```
// code snippet from the tJava component using native java to read a table.
java.sql.Connection tableConnection = null;
tableConnection = (java.sql.Connection) globalMap.get("conn_tMysqlConnection_1");

Statement selectStatement = tableConnection.createStatement();

// Execute statement to get the row count from the table.
ResultSet resultSet = selectStatement.executeQuery("select count(*) from tableA");

// Position the result set to allow for access of its information.
resultSet.next();

// Get the row count from the result set.
context.numberOfRows = resultSet.getInt(1);

resultSet.close();
selectStatement.close();
tableConnection.commit();
tableConnection.close();
```

And... I would be remiss if I did not mention that I found out about needing to use the commit
by an article on the following link.  http://mikeschubert.com/2006/08/03/javanetsocketex/